Postgres - Data insertion into a table - Wrong Visualization
I want to insert a subset of values into a table, called "Regions", made by just two column, "ID_Region" and "Region"
So, I've written this piece of code:
INSERT INTO public."Regions" ("ID_Region", "Region")
VALUES
    (0, 'Africa'),
    (1, 'Asia'),
    (2, 'Central and North America'),
    (3, 'Europe'),
    (4, 'Middle East'),
    (5, 'Nordic countries'),
    (6, 'Oceania'),
    (7, 'South America'),
    (9999, 'Missing')

And as output I have this, not the result expected:



ID_Region
Region




0
"A"


1
"C"


2
"8"


3
"E"


4
"M"


5
"N"


6
"O"


7
"S"


9999
"M"



ID_Region is set as integer
Region is set as Char
Why the result is different from the sql statement?


Are you actually using that query or are you doing this in client software using parameters to the query.  To me it looks like some sort of character indexing is only  supplying the first character of  region, with exception of  1  "C" and 2  "8" have no idea where characters came form there. 2) What is the exact data type of Region e.g. varchar(10) or similar.


"Region is set as Char". If you simply used char, that is the same as char(1) only holding a single character. What is the type for that column actually? If it really is just char -- you have your answer. Use for your data shown char(32) (or larger) or varchar(32) (or larger) to store multiple characters. See PostgreSQL Character Types: CHAR, VARCHAR, and TEXT

See https://dbfiddle.uk/_Br4l5Hj if your table is setup correctly then your insert will work as expected. By thw way: I think you should re-evaulate using double quotes around table and column names - why make these objects case sensitive.

You must have used the special type "char" (Note the quotes!). That type only holds a single character, and will truncate its over-length input rather than throwing an error like other character types do.  (Also, your example is wrong as your rows with ids 1 and 2 do not show what they actually would).
You should not use the special type "char", it is for internal use in system catalogs or things that must interact with them.
It is often handy to read the documentation for the tool you are using.

You have absolutely right Jjanes! I will be more careful next time! Thank you!

And, again, I recommend that you avoid overuse of quoting object names.
